# How to detect if a group is distorting the resulting means?

Tags: r

I have a dataset (see at the end) that consists of different sources `source`. Each row is a different measurement. My goal is to get the average `value` for each `NewCatMo`and `variable`, which I can successfully compute with the following line:

```
means <- as.data.frame(sample %>% group_by(variable, NewCatMo) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value)))
```

However, I want to figure out a way to see if a particular `source` is distorting the results, i.e. doesn't match the patterns of the other `sources`. In case I can find one, I'd exclude it from the data pool.

How can one efficiently detect such an "outlier" group?

An excerpt of the data:

```
structure(list(NewCatMo = c("2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "4 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "4 ASP dominierend", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 ASP dominierend", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"3 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"5 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"4 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 MSP dominierend", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 MSP dominierend", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"4 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 ASP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 ASP dominierend", "3 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "4 Ausgeglichen", "1 ASP dominierend", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "4 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"4 MSP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "3 ASP dominierend", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "4 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"4 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 ASP dominierend", 
"2 ASP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 ASP dominierend", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 ASP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "3 ASP dominierend", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "4 ASP dominierend", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"3 Ausgeglichen", "5 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "3 ASP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 ASP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "5 Ausgeglichen", "2 ASP dominierend", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 ASP dominierend", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"5 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 ASP dominierend", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "5 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"3 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"4 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "4 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "5 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 ASP dominierend", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 ASP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 ASP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", "4 ASP dominierend", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"4 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "5 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "4 ASP dominierend", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "3 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"4 ASP dominierend", "1 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 ASP dominierend", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", 
"1 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen", 
"2 Ausgeglichen", "1 Ausgeglichen"), source = c("Basel Stadt", 
"Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "ag", 
"Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", "nw", "Basel Stadt", "astra", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "astra", "Gemany BAST", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", "astra", "Basel Stadt", "Basel Land", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "astra", "Basel Stadt", "Gemany BAST", 
"Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Essen", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", 
"astra", "nw", "Basel Land", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "astra_basel", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Essen", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Essen", "Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", 
"astra", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Essen", 
"Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", "Gemany BAST", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "ag", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", 
"ag", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Essen", 
"Basel Stadt", "astra", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", 
"Basel Land", "Basel Land", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "ag", 
"Basel Land", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "ag", "astra", "astra_basel", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", "astra", "ag", "Gemany BAST", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", 
"Basel Stadt", "astra_basel", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", 
"astra", "Gemany BAST", "astra", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "nw", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Essen", "UTD19_Essen", "UTD19_Essen", 
"astra_basel", "ag", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", 
"Basel Stadt", "astra", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", "UTD19_Essen", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Essen", "UTD19_Paris", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "Basel Land", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Basel Stadt", "Gemany BAST", "astra", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "nw", "Gemany BAST", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "astra", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "astra", "Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", 
"ag", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "astra", "Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", 
"Basel Land", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", 
"astra", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Essen", 
"Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "astra", "Basel Land", 
"Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "Basel Stadt", 
"Basel Stadt", "Basel Land", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Basel Stadt", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", "Basel Land", "UTD19_Essen", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", "Basel Land", "Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Essen", "Basel Stadt", 
"Basel Stadt", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", "astra", "astra_basel", "Basel Stadt", 
"astra", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", 
"Basel Land", "UTD19_Essen", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "astra_basel", 
"Basel Stadt", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", 
"Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "ag", "UTD19_Paris", 
"UTD19_Paris", "ag", "astra_basel", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", 
"Gemany BAST", "astra", "Gemany BAST", "astra", "nw", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "Basel Stadt", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "ag", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Stadt", "Basel Stadt", 
"Basel Land", "UTD19_Essen", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Land", "Gemany BAST", 
"Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", 
"ag", "UTD19_Essen", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", 
"astra", "Basel Stadt", "Basel Land", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", 
"astra", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", 
"Basel Stadt", "Basel Land", "UTD19_Essen", "Basel Stadt", "Gemany BAST", 
"astra", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", 
"Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "astra_basel", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", "astra", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", "ag", 
"UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "astra", 
"UTD19_Essen", "Gemany BAST", "astra_basel", "astra", "Gemany BAST", 
"Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Essen", "ag", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "astra_basel", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", 
"UTD19_Essen", "Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", "Gemany BAST", "ag", 
"Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", 
"Gemany BAST", "astra", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", 
"Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "ag", 
"UTD19_Paris", "Basel Land", "Basel Land", "Basel Stadt", "Basel Land", 
"astra", "astra", "Basel Stadt", "Gemany BAST", "Basel Stadt", 
"astra", "Basel Land", "Gemany BAST", "UTD19_Paris", "UTD19_Paris", 
"astra", "Basel Stadt", "astra"), variable = structure(c(18L, 
17L, 18L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 
24L, 21L, 15L, 23L, 2L, 18L, 24L, 18L, 15L, 20L, 18L, 11L, 20L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 23L, 24L, 23L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
13L, 6L, 17L, 8L, 23L, 10L, 21L, 23L, 22L, 11L, 2L, 23L, 19L, 
2L, 4L, 23L, 14L, 4L, 20L, 16L, 20L, 22L, 18L, 8L, 17L, 16L, 
13L, 14L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 21L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 21L, 8L, 24L, 
15L, 10L, 18L, 3L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 22L, 5L, 17L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 12L, 
23L, 4L, 14L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 7L, 21L, 
8L, 1L, 17L, 22L, 13L, 23L, 3L, 16L, 15L, 17L, 23L, 17L, 8L, 
10L, 6L, 2L, 13L, 7L, 10L, 21L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 14L, 10L, 23L, 
3L, 23L, 15L, 11L, 17L, 12L, 6L, 23L, 20L, 16L, 16L, 5L, 11L, 
23L, 13L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 17L, 20L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 18L, 22L, 8L, 23L, 
10L, 3L, 1L, 20L, 22L, 10L, 12L, 18L, 8L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 5L, 
6L, 24L, 22L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 17L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 17L, 
14L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 22L, 19L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 20L, 21L, 
11L, 19L, 16L, 24L, 9L, 17L, 1L, 21L, 23L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 
10L, 19L, 21L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 16L, 7L, 16L, 12L, 20L, 22L, 
1L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 20L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 17L, 6L, 15L, 3L, 
23L, 17L, 15L, 7L, 24L, 8L, 21L, 22L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 7L, 23L, 
21L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 18L, 23L, 2L, 8L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 22L, 
6L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 24L, 13L, 18L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 6L, 11L, 
16L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 23L, 3L, 15L, 8L, 15L, 3L, 12L, 22L, 10L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 21L, 5L, 21L, 12L, 18L, 22L, 12L, 20L, 19L, 3L, 14L, 
20L, 18L, 11L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 8L, 15L, 12L, 14L, 20L, 8L, 3L, 
21L, 3L, 12L, 22L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 14L, 6L, 18L, 20L, 9L, 16L, 
24L, 10L, 16L, 14L, 1L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 24L, 9L, 14L, 18L, 
14L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 12L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 6L, 23L, 13L, 5L, 22L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 16L, 12L, 1L, 15L, 19L, 17L, 18L, 16L, 15L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 22L, 12L, 23L, 8L, 5L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 24L, 23L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 22L, 6L), .Label = c("h_1", "h_2", "h_3", 
"h_4", "h_5", "h_6", "h_7", "h_8", "h_9", "h_10", "h_11", "h_12", 
"h_13", "h_14", "h_15", "h_16", "h_17", "h_18", "h_19", "h_20", 
"h_21", "h_22", "h_23", "h_24"), class = "factor"), value = c(8.65184155663655, 
8.17033919286952, 5.623368, 2.0059425, 0.411583125091871, 6.34857256937512, 
4.84582534842405, 0.494771168334645, 0.16629711751663, 5.61112466455233, 
0.4546605, 0.9006895, 5.49545651233232, 5.58788531409511, 8.962613, 
2.000245, 3.00196660366184, 5.659085, 2.10866518658433, 2.2200477, 
6.209234, 4.106194, 6.75897906190349, 6.32761053754899, 4.732729, 
5.15264051511189, 6.7524115755627, 6.609918, 5.016449, 5.531415, 
6.76581483033096, 0.796689539613048, 5.79124153809937, 0.3696948, 
7.59887005649717, 0.472489, 2.14375072264729, 1.594679, 1.34357005758157, 
1.11234705228031, 0.880263750495701, 1.553566, 6.224515, 3.65479408952712, 
5.136163, 8.133569, 4.0344338, 4.704627, 5.5591188, 1.694927, 
2.45461584149029, 4.90765494357283, 2.2720816, 2.084183, 4.29511819520356, 
2.7860177, 1.5550341, 2.425324, 5.91318218069956, 1.8399743, 
6.49693161932149, 4.827517, 4.79534593808436, 3.9283688, 4.896763, 
5.35372012196369, 6.97072608236937, 8.76941924135062, 5.64342, 
5.503304, 2.18340611353712, 6.49713361752168, 4.494183, 6.17381668513535, 
5.0566957, 0.237530182251183, 5.75168550204944, 5.708417, 0.760006926389417, 
2.885858, 3.875185, 1.49129519141617, 8.51970988369297, 4.2925632734976, 
9.46805289189462, 1.235571, 3.0716186, 10.7629929966826, 2.62200956937799, 
2.0077201, 0.80450522928399, 9.06368536634059, 1.702862, 0.4119431, 
1.052719, 6.50175189814743, 2.08781086889776, 0.4387931, 6.58536585365854, 
7.85412857519283, 4.669889, 5.009677, 0.590383850457628, 2.142322, 
1.58600907389529, 1.31250471190187, 1.723849, 2.4832947, 3.04757505780358, 
4.44027517198249, 0.7493395, 6.93732795431381, 3.10073, 6.52851618696948, 
2.9914035, 0.440587845926066, 5.692045, 6.486989, 5.22708, 1.98100407055631, 
6.093403, 3.532283, 5.734816, 2.5078229, 0.6964752, 6.165265, 
6.20882411659014, 5.163705, 5.4615146, 0.941611950606221, 0.693634797472859, 
0.3337456, 0.61359022003841, 7.05218617771509, 5.797192, 2.9131853, 
1.5008704, 4.0501351, 6.353689, 4.292261, 5.950723, 6.47017260522863, 
2.83938409379856, 2.5339614502199, 6.384592, 6.54039347007116, 
8.39365017009409, 1.115454, 4.992286, 2.19251336898396, 4.965045, 
0.621413591922332, 4.316707, 3.84862091084028, 6.39105339625938, 
7.085162, 5.39446126671713, 4.650186, 6.550985, 6.272198, 4.2080558, 
7.18432641378635, 2.200706, 4.41102250933683, 1.15634786798362, 
2.270509, 5.911406, 2.55965871217171, 5.33448961289267, 5.26081498612809, 
8.3927591881514, 6.65075034106412, 7.978812, 6.641591, 6.06719845298525, 
0.800937935441839, 1.57360406091371, 0.733563679330365, 3.3983625, 
7.3855662431038, 1.80675569520817, 7.75019, 5.598539, 6.47680293982545, 
0.915956736344838, 0.5627759, 1.07985936715218, 1.2057856, 4.746998499306, 
6.630348, 6.13690761129727, 0.861805364278329, 5.31975093623733, 
1.0281733, 3.36100830249075, 8.51695964347611, 6.17326057298772, 
4.01524032825322, 1.2777318, 4.41753114607634, 2.0059425, 4.74753674861492, 
2.89745812830509, 5.060319, 6.26152074475423, 5.977008, 0.971293175550107, 
4.0197461212976, 6.95200096723492, 1.2193017, 5.7322831, 1.47865013518981, 
5.308355, 5.397883, 6.38552916386396, 4.98007, 5.54633209669169, 
6.34705447374908, 3.67965367965368, 1.23228678792528, 5.90371057364347, 
2.3447684, 2.678668, 6.9789737207687, 3.066005, 6.75928309092674, 
6.68485675306958, 4.63351325171736, 4.3530517, 2.196203, 1.4175422, 
5.72876222766947, 7.29465591283664, 6.480788, 4.443325, 7.13611081960332, 
0.9226699, 1.9752095, 0.542453431770159, 3.82984, 7.98180538257432, 
1.36024082952392, 6.377324, 0.645161290322581, 3.269274, 7.088463, 
5.82621798091411, 2.2316384180791, 3.996649, 3.370202, 3.37510945594908, 
2.03884433278578, 6.07543520560328, 6.67471773366945, 3.97096941420425, 
1.0866509, 4.3136495, 5.9661037, 6.153442, 8.63250205535763, 
6.01409, 5.016195, 10.5206073752711, 2.267942, 0.612184609360251, 
7.61066890099148, 2.36265343935358, 2.691538, 3.69003976710566, 
2.928347, 1.63147792706334, 0.8256862, 4.55476420297245, 4.74694303496043, 
4.471906, 5.47945205479452, 6.71607210258668, 1.5205157, 5.7264604774599, 
0.258016955399926, 0.600823663630314, 2.72344639762317, 0.472232, 
5.9126700071582, 5.965864, 6.32593213238375, 4.06224406224406, 
4.75519097667265, 2.074864, 0.330976753785815, 6.19699042407661, 
8.12371472431138, 6.59147268218543, 0.185958834318321, 6.13873542050338, 
3.8342827, 6.00790529417789, 0.0631711939355654, 0.4575177, 0.978604, 
2.74463007159905, 0.506433641682225, 2.594233, 6.35097493036212, 
7.25395548404398, 2.68445710904797, 6.068527, 4.524872, 5.899451, 
0.9261447, 7.11067425589038, 4.33129874003151, 6.49616925009661, 
6.23003194888179, 7.435502, 9.91895618805906, 4.88074549166913, 
8.746324, 4.990349, 5.87180585960981, 5.28816, 3.7221749178932, 
6.67276975383532, 0.825581, 3.371588, 1.7827818, 4.964329, 2.22113902727501, 
0.8468298, 2.0652739, 4.5886375375994, 8.64840496809743, 5.743543, 
1.1028479, 6.78749543851113, 4.45246604547006, 6.639419, 5.785825, 
3.862972, 3.00782458569661, 7.24111335451348, 5.64003317666574, 
4.048483, 5.521921, 4.897938, 6.59526493799324, 5.389899, 1.337988, 
5.90675832073335, 5.585792, 7.989053, 6.61641555436459, 6.56997249581913, 
4.2123098, 0.764778804537534, 5.4476, 8.29562594268477, 6.712732, 
3.97406989853439, 1.631472, 2.23355183296917, 5.352791, 0.910214, 
2.49980467853808, 1.11044143123562, 0.550533973741274, 0.0825763831544178, 
6.57112411341173, 5.96104047473053, 2.386707, 6.70316853432066, 
6.52542372881356, 7.28742844107784, 6.297722, 5.500446, 5.547755, 
1.1495986, 4.24467778010958, 0.7524702, 4.70824380938125, 0.4464605, 
0.116959064327485, 3.7012895, 7.03627852545348, 1.62241887905605, 
1.85642435449063, 0.487115021998743, 5.985189, 5.036543, 6.331569664903, 
1.24387860640796, 3.0204967832484, 2.716195, 0.748362956033676, 
3.07891393711771, 3.09426, 0.9595575, 4.237099, 2.78116613808246, 
2.280541)), row.names = c(11775L, 11088L, 12310L, 1197L, 1675L, 
4974L, 6550L, 909L, 2192L, 4865L, 110L, 3966L, 11952L, 11356L, 
13100L, 16096L, 14272L, 10294L, 15641L, 1325L, 12381L, 16497L, 
12117L, 9950L, 13296L, 12040L, 7112L, 13803L, 9593L, 9158L, 9710L, 
375L, 6541L, 2043L, 5831L, 3405L, 15652L, 16070L, 15336L, 45L, 
2493L, 1311L, 8958L, 3872L, 11720L, 4936L, 15720L, 6901L, 14325L, 
15909L, 14976L, 7278L, 1187L, 15392L, 12868L, 1175L, 2690L, 15881L, 
9002L, 2654L, 13427L, 11021L, 13430L, 15185L, 12257L, 5209L, 
11351L, 10699L, 8932L, 9556L, 3581L, 7904L, 6828L, 4283L, 14377L, 
2357L, 5776L, 5513L, 3040L, 13991L, 5360L, 16352L, 10005L, 6461L, 
11979L, 1900L, 4761L, 11888L, 4211L, 15176L, 2954L, 11202L, 3605L, 
1457L, 4064L, 7931L, 15282L, 2217L, 9116L, 12858L, 10979L, 8886L, 
445L, 4615L, 15533L, 16167L, 15989L, 4633L, 14215L, 5071L, 167L, 
11444L, 14714L, 8737L, 15835L, 1835L, 10965L, 10263L, 11654L, 
15338L, 11706L, 5326L, 6909L, 4130L, 1364L, 8390L, 4282L, 6796L, 
14463L, 3871L, 928L, 845L, 1833L, 9061L, 6911L, 15696L, 2015L, 
15801L, 10364L, 7530L, 11585L, 7827L, 3653L, 15595L, 13782L, 
10417L, 10791L, 2949L, 7454L, 15285L, 8952L, 1821L, 6089L, 5649L, 
11423L, 13789L, 5107L, 7026L, 6156L, 12369L, 15084L, 5190L, 15372L, 
6443L, 1407L, 539L, 13615L, 14717L, 6573L, 7998L, 11898L, 5141L, 
13052L, 12623L, 10429L, 3006L, 3680L, 16220L, 15120L, 5146L, 
4195L, 5708L, 11543L, 6420L, 935L, 1366L, 31L, 2594L, 5223L, 
11213L, 9215L, 1061L, 6466L, 3326L, 14537L, 12472L, 7218L, 6291L, 
2634L, 6267L, 1259L, 13423L, 14153L, 7488L, 12883L, 10897L, 16229L, 
5601L, 11302L, 684L, 14469L, 15571L, 7563L, 7540L, 9409L, 8139L, 
6546L, 12512L, 14027L, 404L, 6675L, 4731L, 642L, 10661L, 4843L, 
10619L, 7909L, 13391L, 15170L, 471L, 1280L, 5221L, 5207L, 5720L, 
13223L, 10381L, 180L, 1294L, 2529L, 474L, 11098L, 3693L, 10371L, 
1391L, 15818L, 11159L, 9719L, 4448L, 16444L, 5457L, 14088L, 14574L, 
7175L, 9362L, 13865L, 4795L, 15716L, 14361L, 12973L, 11902L, 
12954L, 10972L, 11896L, 15320L, 992L, 5042L, 14904L, 15406L, 
13598L, 14708L, 3572L, 3280L, 5896L, 5168L, 16404L, 8332L, 12022L, 
1324L, 7879L, 816L, 1000L, 14548L, 4083L, 7208L, 10985L, 7634L, 
4446L, 5073L, 15893L, 1832L, 9752L, 5155L, 9910L, 1644L, 7614L, 
15082L, 6679L, 1520L, 3456L, 4020L, 13902L, 3048L, 13938L, 7626L, 
11950L, 14978L, 8244L, 13314L, 12981L, 1959L, 9376L, 13399L, 
12044L, 6980L, 11759L, 11344L, 13579L, 4952L, 10280L, 7955L, 
9626L, 13218L, 5219L, 2005L, 13934L, 1928L, 8188L, 14848L, 3394L, 
1323L, 5261L, 4573L, 9571L, 3957L, 11834L, 13397L, 5701L, 10951L, 
16521L, 6635L, 10695L, 9124L, 597L, 8814L, 8882L, 8515L, 8484L, 
16603L, 5924L, 9075L, 11943L, 9423L, 10777L, 15106L, 1152L, 8278L, 
11899L, 13086L, 12667L, 3556L, 15239L, 8816L, 3448L, 14878L, 
3147L, 395L, 1509L, 10814L, 7894L, 594L, 10085L, 12752L, 11485L, 
11945L, 10841L, 10321L, 3960L, 4512L, 2028L, 4496L, 3301L, 811L, 
15121L, 7659L, 15410L, 5123L, 2981L, 8401L, 6407L, 8323L, 16353L, 
15493L, 3640L, 3691L, 3910L, 5418L, 3319L, 5636L, 14553L, 3608L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You could perform a one-way ANOVA (`aov()`), which would test if any group is different from any other group. You can then perform a post-hoc test with `TukeyHSD` to find which is the different group. However, the easiest approach is to plot your data by source and inspect it visually.

Comment: To add to the visual inspection, if you use the command `boxplot(value ~ source, data = df)` where `df` is your dataframe, you can investigate the data visually.

Comment: not sure I understand, you are looking for observations that are outliers within each source, or within each variable~NewCatMo combination?

Comment: I am looking for sources that have in general a different distribution from the other sources.